# is there a way to do session manage using sinatra framework with cloudfoundry?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, cloud-foundry

none of the tutorials I found online seem to cover this. I mean that do but I'm not seeing what they say I should be seeing when I do the check. is this because I'm on the cloudfoundry platform? if you could direct me to some literature or give me a hint that would be great! I am trying to implement session control by some storing information in a cookie,review that cookie, and compare it to a session table in my db each time the user makes a HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward. Just make sure you have sessions enabled in Sinatra and use the session_id as a key in your database. I created a little example at https://gist.github.com/danhigham/4943057

The example gets a tweet from twitter as json and retrieves a collection from Redis using the session_id as a key, adds the tweet to the collection as json and then stores it back in the same record.

I have also pushed the example to http://session-tweet.cloudfoundry.com